# Created a script to toggle lid close action (sleep/do nothing) I can see it take effect, but it doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, guid, power-management

I've made a vbs script which basically toggles the close lid action between Sleep and DoNothing.

The idea is to have an icon on my desktop to save going ControlPanel>PowerOptions>ChangeWhatClosingTheLidDoes every time. I'm on Windows 7 x64 by the way.

When I run it, in control panel I can see that the lid close action changes, however when I actually close the lid, there is no change in behavior.

Any suggestions on what could be preventing the system from obeying it's instructions??

It's really strange that I can see the change in ControlPanel>PowerOptions, but it doesn't work...

Video demo here, not sure how to embed...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1yjiTMgnzk&feature=youtu.be

The vbs script basically checks what values are in a .bat file, reverses them and runs it. Really simple;

```
ToggleLidAction.vbs
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ForReading = 1

Dim outPutFile

Dim objFSO, objFile, objOutFile, strLine
dim sleepLine1, sleepLine2, doNothingLine1, doNothingLine2

sleepLine1 = "powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 1"
sleepLine2 = "powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 1"
doNothingLine1 = "powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 0"
doNothingLine2 = "powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-  eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 0"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("ToggleLidAction.bat", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    strDoNothing = Instr(strLine,"powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685- ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 0")
    strSleep = Instr(strLine,"powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-     ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 1")
Loop
objFile.Close

Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
obj.DeleteFile("ToggleLidAction.bat")

If strDoNothing Then
outPutFile = "ToggleLidAction.bat"
    Set objOutFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outPutFile,ForAppending)
    objOutFile.WriteLine ""& sleepLine1 &""
    objOutFile.WriteLine ""& sleepLine2 &""
    Msgbox ("The System will now Sleep when the lid is closed.")
else if strSleep Then
    outPutFile = "ToggleLidAction.bat"
    Set objOutFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outPutFile,ForAppending)
    objOutFile.WriteLine ""& doNothingLine1 &""
    objOutFile.WriteLine ""& doNothingLine2 &""
    Msgbox ("The System will now continue running when the lid is closed.")
end if
end if
objOutFile.Close

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "ToggleLidAction.bat C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe", 0
```

ToggleLidAction.bat

```
powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 0
powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 0
```

or

```
powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-      9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 1
powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 1
```

Though I don't think it's a problem with the code, because as I said, and you can see on the video, I can see the change in Control Panel.

Thanks for reading,

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, eliminate the "code" from the problem. If you run the `powercfg` statements from a command line, does it work?

Comment: Sorry, should have put it in there. No, it has the exact same results.

Comment: You may want to remove all the VBScript code then and re-post your question more simply as a "Windows" or "Command Line" question, focusing just on your `powercfg` statement(s). You'll get better answers that way from people who understand `powercfg` but not VBScript.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for your response...

Comment: New thread added here;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959861/computer-not-obeying-powercfg-guid-command-line-instructions

If anybody has any suggestions, thanks...

Answer (score 2):

[Copied from the comment found on this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602077/cant-get-powercfg-setacvalueindex-to-work-with-changing-lid-closing-actions-s?rq=1):

Turns out what was missing was `powercfg -setactive`.

powercfg needs one of those to update changes to the current scheme. So to change your settings via cmd line/batch file you would need to run:

```
powercfg -setacvalueindex Scheme_GUID Sub_GUID Setting_GUID SettingIndex
```

followed by:

```
powercfg -setactive Scheme_GUID
```